# ALGLIB метод наименьших квадратов

Tags: c++, qt

Не смог ни где найти примера на AGLIB реализации МНК, функции полинома 3 порядка.

Поделитесь примером.

Comment: Да там же самому написать - составить матрицу и решить систему уравнений... Ну, не 10 минут, но никак не больше часа-двух.

Comment: А в alglib этой функции нету ?

Comment: Понятия не имею...

Comment: Да и еще Alglib платный. Сам напишу.